# Is it possible to predict just one row from my data set?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a dataset that looks like the table below. I would like, on clicking on the link button to predict according to the Label field. So, my question is, as I want to just predict one row of my dataset, How can I split my data into training and testing set according to this code from sci-kit-learn?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
```

Below is my view to give you an idea of what I would like to do.

```
def prediction_view(request):
template='index.html'
.
.
.
train=Pull_Requests.objects.all()


    features_col = ['Comments', 'LC_added', 'LC_deleted', 'Commits', 'Changed_files', 'Evaluation_time','First_status','Reputation'] # This also test
        class_label=['Label']
    X = train[features_col].dropna() # This also test
    # y = train.Label # This also test
    y=train[class_label]

    random_state = 0
    test_size=request.POST.get('test_size')

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=random_state, test_size=test_size)
    clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)

    classification_report={'accuracy':Accuracy, 'pricision':Precision, 'recall':Recall, 'f1_score':F1_meseaure}
    importance_features={'importances_feautre':importances_feautres}
    data={
        'new_data':new_data,
        'classification_report':classification_report,
        'importance_feature':importance_features,
        'features':features_col,
             }
return render(request,template,data)
```

[Dataset sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSxUX.png):
[image: Dataset sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cross-validation you can use `LeaveOneOut` from [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html).  For example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut 

loo = LeaveOneOut()
loo.get_n_splits(X)

for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
```

Note that, given *n* samples, this will give you *n* folds.  If *n* is large this can become computationally expensive (although as you have relatively few features, *n* would probably need to become very large).

An alternative approach is to generate a random integer (within the range of train's index) as the index to use for each test:

```
import random

max_ind = train.index[-1]
rand_int = random.randint(0, max_ind)

test_idx = pd.Index([rand_int])
train_idx = train[~test_idx]

X_train, y_train = X[train_idx], y[train_idx]
X_test, y_test = X[test_idx], y[test_idx]
```

This assumes `train`'s index increases monotonically.  You can check if this is the case using `train.index.is_monotonic_increasing` [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.is_monotonic_increasing.html) and use `train.reset_index(drop=True)` [(docs)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if required.  Alternatively, you could use `train.shape[0]` instead, in which case you should confirm each value in the index to be unique and less than or equal to `train.shape[0]`.